# Node.js - method is returning UNDEFINED when parsing XML

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, asynchronous

I'm parsing a hardcoded XML-structure inside a class in Node.js. The problem is that the parsing is done asynchronously, which causes the method to return the default value (null).

```
function Codeorder() {
    // Hardcodet XML-tree as string
    this.order = "  <root> \
                            <order instancename=\"flashlibraries\" opens=\"true\" />\
                                <order instancename=\"TESTTEST\" opens=\"true\" />\
                            <order instancename=\"flashlibraries\" opens=\"false\" />\
                        </root>";
    this.orderXML = null;
}

Codeorder.prototype.getOrderedCodepieces = function(instancename) {

    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    parseString(this.order, function (err, result) {
        return result; // This doesn't work
    });

    // Return "All OK"; 
}

module.exports = Codeorder;
```

How to I get the method to wait for the parser to complete and then return the XML content?

Comment: You don't. Accept a callback as second parameter in `getOrderedCodepieces` and call that function when `parseString` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: What you want can be achieved that but it may not work with future version of xml2js.

```
Codeorder.prototype.getOrderedCodepieces = function(instancename) {

    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var ret = {};
    parseString(this.order, {async: false}, function(err, data) {
      ret.err = err;
      ret.data = data;
    });
    if (ret.err) {
      throw ret.err;
    }
    return ret.data;
}
```

Once you have this change you can will have the data you want as the return value of `getOrderedCodepieces()`:

```
var c = new Codeorder();
var data = c.getOrderedCodepieces();
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

This relies on the `async` option of the parser being supported. As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) it may change in the future:

> sync (default false): Should the callbacks be async? This might be an
>   incompatible change if your code depends on sync execution of
>   callbacks. Future versions of xml2js might change this

Comment: Works flawlessly - thank you for your help and the info, regarding future versions of xml2js.